# Calculate the loss of discriminator in keras

Tags: python, neural-network, keras

I want to calculate the loss error of the discriminator in keras, however, without updating the weights of the network. So far, I am using the following function (train_on_batch) to update the weights of the network using the gradient descent:

```
d_loss = d.train_on_batch(X, y)
```

However, what I want to do is firstly to calculate the d_loss and then to update the weights according to the d_loss value. How can i do so in Keras?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
d.evaluate(x, y)
```

will return all losses and metrics defined in your model.
Refer to the [documentation](https://keras.io/models/model/#evaluate).

```
d.test_on_batch(x, y)
```

might also be of interest.

Comment: Are you sure that they returned the same thing? I have the d.train_on_batch and then d.test_on_batch and the result is different.

Comment: Apparently, the evaluate function is what I need. Thanks a lot for the quick response!!

Comment: Read the documentation. If you have a single loss, test_on_batch and train_on_batch should both return a scalar value (obviously it would be numerically different, since one is pre and the other post-training)

Comment: Actually I want to update the discriminator only if the d_loss is less than a threshold, Can I undo the changes of the gradient update somehow??

Comment: I've never heard of that before; you could call train_on_batch only as long as your test_on_batch satisfies the loss condition you've set. Otherwise you could customize your loss function and mask it (i.e. set it to zero) for the samples fitting your condition.

Comment: I want to constraint the discriminator of being really strong for the beginning. I think it is called mode collapse. Thus, I would like to update the weight when the loss is greater than a threshold.

Comment: "you could call train_on_batch only as long as your test_on_batch satisfies the loss condition you've set". That way the weights are not changed at all. therefore, I will have always the same weights.

Comment: train_on_batch does update the weights, so you could call it after calling test_on_batch, getting your losses and making the conditional checks

Comment: Ok then I maybe am confused. I want to update the weights and if I check that the loss is super small to undo the update of the weights. Which is the function that updates the weights?

Comment: The train function is the one updating your weights. Another way to do what you're trying to do is store model checkpoints and re-load them with a custom callback whenever your condition is met https://keras.io/callbacks/

Comment: I will try to have a look. Here i found the proposed solution for the mode collapse btw: https://www.reddit.com/r/MachineLearning/comments/5asl74/discussion_discriminator_converging_to_0_loss_in/